# GROUP BY with CASE - tsql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, case, common-table-expression

I have a select which looks like the following:

```
SELECT 
        ReportingDate
    ,   PortfolioID
    ,   PortfolioNme

    ,   CASE
            WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoCountry' THEN Infoportal.dbo.fn_Generic_ProperCase(Country)
            WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoEquity'  THEN Region
        END                 AS Country

    ,   RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PortfolioID ORDER BY SUM(Percentage) DESC, CASE WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoCountry' THEN Country WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoEquity' THEN Region END) AS [Rank]
    ,   SUM(Percentage)     AS [Weight]

FROM @Worktable as WT

WHERE WT.IssueType1 <> '010' AND WT.IssueType2 <> '055'

GROUP BY    WT.ReportingDate
        ,   WT.PortfolioID
        ,   WT.PortfolioNme
        ,   CASE
                WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoCountry' THEN WT.Country
                WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoEquity'  THEN WT.Region
            END
```

What i'm trying to do is group by country or region depending upon the @ReportType and show the sum of the percentage and a rank.

However I keep getting the error:

> *Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 349
>
>   Column '@Worktable.Country' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
>   Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 350
>
>   Column '@Worktable.Region' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.*

This is so easy and it is really annoying me.  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See also:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77130/how-do-i-select-data-with-a-case-statement-and-group-by

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe a CTE would simplfy what you're trying to do:

```
;WITH WT AS (
    SELECT 
        ReportingDate
    ,   PortfolioID
    ,   PortfolioNme

    ,   CASE
            WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoCountry' 
              THEN Infoportal.dbo.fn_Generic_ProperCase(Country)
            WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoEquity'  
              THEN Region
        END AS Country
    ,   Percentage
FROM @Worktable
WHERE IssueType1 <> '010' AND IssueType2 <> '055'
)
SELECT 
        ReportingDate
    ,   PortfolioID
    ,   PortfolioNme
    ,   Country
    ,   RANK() OVER (
          PARTITION BY PortfolioID 
          ORDER BY SUM(Percentage) DESC, Country) AS [Rank]
    ,   SUM(Percentage) AS [Weight]
FROM WT
GROUP BY
        ReportingDate
    ,   PortfolioID
    ,   PortfolioNme
    ,   Country
```

Comment: Knew it would be easy, Friday afternoon brain freeze.  Cheers mate.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ReportingDate, PortfolioID, PortfolioNme, Country, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PortfolioID ORDER BY SUM(Percentage) DESC, CountryOrRegion) AS [Rank],   SUM(Percentage)     AS [Weight]
from (
    SELECT 
            ReportingDate
        ,   PortfolioID
        ,   PortfolioNme
        , CASE WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoCountry' THEN Country WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoEquity' THEN Region END as CountryOrRegion
        ,   CASE
                WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoCountry' THEN Infoportal.dbo.fn_Generic_ProperCase(Country)
                WHEN @ReportType = 'GeoEquity'  THEN Region
            END                 AS Country
    FROM @Worktable as WT
    WHERE WT.IssueType1 <> '010' AND WT.IssueType2 <> '055'
) t
GROUP BY    WT.ReportingDate
        ,   WT.PortfolioID
        ,   WT.PortfolioNme
        ,   CountryOrRegion
```